# Vuejs dynamically toggle class is not working in Laravel Blade Template

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am novice in VueJs and As I am trying to implement the basic toggle class functionality using v-bind property of VueJs in my Laravel project. I am not getting the value of variable `className` while rendering of the page. Please guide me where I am doing wrong. The code is given below:

```
<div id="root">
  <button type="button" v-bind:class="{'className':isLoading}" v-on:click="toggleClass">Toggle Me</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript is:

```
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#root',
        data: {
            className:"color-red",
            isLoading:false
        },
        methods:{
            toggleClass(){
                this.isLoading=true;
                this.className="color-blue";
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

Style is:

```
<style>
    .color-red{
        background-color:red;
    }
    .color-blue{
        background-color:blue;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing your approaches slightly. The main issue is in `v-bind:class="{'className':isLoading}"`. This directive, the way you wrote it, toggles a class with the name `"className"` (literally that, not the value of the variable `className`) to your element if `isLoading` is `true`. If it's `false`, it doesn't assign any class.

Looking at your code, it seems you're actually trying to set two different classes depending on what the value of `isLoading` is. The easiest way to do this would be to use `v-bind:class="isLoading ? 'color-red' : 'color-blue"`. Take a look at a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/2162/).

An even better solution that doesn't pollute your template with logic is to move that expression to a computed property, [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/2163/).

Answer (score 0):

You can not have `className` as well as a variable name, as vue expects it as actual CSS class, [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#ad) suggests one more way, have class object like following:

```
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#root',
        data: {
            classObj:{ "color-red" : true } ,
            isLoading:false
        },
        methods:{
            toggleClass(){
                this.isLoading=true;
                this.classObj = { "color-blue" : true};
            }
        }
    })
</script>


<div id="root">
  <button type="button" v-bind:class="classObj" v-on:click="toggleClass">Toggle Me</button>
</div>
```